# Investigating slow simple queries in JDBC and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, hikaricp

`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` is taking ~20x longer to execute than if it were run directly via the shell. I've logged with timers to determine that this method is the culprit.

The query and some DB info (*ignoring the Java issue for the moment*):

`mysql> SELECT username from users where user_id = 1;` // lightning fast

Running that same query 1,000 times via mysqlslap is also lightning fast.

```
mysqlslap --create-schema=mydb --user=root -p --query="select username from phpbb_users where user_id = 1" --number-of-queries=1000 --concurrency=1

Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.051 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.051 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.051 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 1
        Average number of queries per client: 1000
```

**The Problem:** Performing the same query in JDBC slows things significantly. In a for loop calling the below `queryUsername()` 1,000 times (this is called in the Main method, which isn't shown here) takes around 872ms. That's ~17x slower! I've tracked down the heavy usage by placing timers in various spots (omitted some for brevity). The primary suspect is `stmt.executeQuery()` which took 776ms of the 872ms runtime.

```
public static String queryUsername() {
        String username = "";
        // DBCore.getConnection() returns HikariDataSource.getConnection() implementation exactly as per https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp
        try (Connection connection = DBCore.getConnection(); 
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username from phpbb_users where user_id = ?");) {
            stmt.setInt(1, 1);  // just looking for user_id 1 for now
            // Google timer used to measure how long executeQuery() is taking
            // Another Timer is used outside of this method call to see how long
            // total execution takes. 
            // Approximately 1 second in for loop calling this method 1000 times
            Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.createStarted(); 
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();) {
                s.stop(); // stopping the timer after executeQuery() has been called
                timeElapsed  += s.elapsed(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    username = rs.getString("username"); // the query returns 1 record
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return username;
    }
```

**Additional context and things tried**:

[image: EXPLAIN statement]

[image]

- `SHOW OPEN TABLES` has several tables open, but all have In_use=0 and Name_locked=0.
- `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` looks healthy.
- user_id is an indexed primary key
- The Server is an Upcloud $5/month 1-Core, 1GB RAM running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64). Mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
- JDBC Driver is mysql-connector-java_8.0.23.jar, which was obtained from mysql-connector-java_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04_all via https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

[image: Server HTOP]

Comment: UPDATE: months later ... I was able to reduce my query time in half by updating the JDBC Driver to mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to achieve faster query times by switching over to MariaDB Connector/J 2.7.4 https://kb.askmonty.org/en/about-the-mariadb-java-client/

Answer (score 1):

Don't reconnect each time.  Open the connection at the start; reuse it until the web page (or program) is finished.

Comment: Or maybe use a DBCP for a serious program.

Comment: I'm having mixed thoughts. A Connection object is obtained via HikariDataSource.getConnection(). Is this incorrect? (that's what the DBCore.getConnection() above is doing)

Comment: I would expect a DBCP to take _some_ time.  Leave that for multiple users connecting to the same or different web pages.  Your test Select is about as simple as it can be.  (`SELECT 1` is even simpler.)  What you seem to be doing is timing the connection, not the `SELECT`.  Am I misreading the code?

Comment: Where is the loop?  Slap is running the entire thing 1000 times?

Comment: Independently of the Java application I tested the query using slap, 1000 times to get a feel for the query speed ("fast"). The above method queryUsername() is being called in the Main method nested in a for loop 1000 times, which is "slow". Yeah, you're right we're basically timing the connection since the query is so simple. I'm surprised that each method call to getUsername() is taking ~17x longer than executing the query directly in the shell.

Comment: I modified the query to be SELECT 1 .. running the method 1000 times took ~800ms. Is this speed normal? ..

Comment: @VILLAINbryan - An average of 0.8ms for sequentially running 1000 "point queries".  This is feasible.  No I/O would be needed (after perhaps the first one); the rest is CPU and network.  I rarely see a query running much faster than 1ms.  Another interesting test would be to have 10 processes each running a query 100 times.  _That_ is likely to take less than 800ms.

Comment: The OP is using - I assume by the name - a connection pool (HikariCP), so essentially they are already reusing connections.

Comment: Yes, we're using HikariCP and calling getConnection() on the HikariDataSource, as per the manual. The connections are being reused and managed via the pool. The execution of the code that is taking a long time is the stmt.executeQuery() part, which is about 89% of the runtime of the method, and not calling getConnection(). I've tested by grabbing one connection and using it for the entirety of 1,000 calls - no improvements.

Comment: "being reused" is ambiguous.  I suspect the intent is "after on client finishes, another can use 'reuse' the connection".  Sure you could do that withing a single client instance, but this is not the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you are comparing different realities.

When running mysqlslap you are most likely using Unix Domain Sockets in the communication between the tool and MySQL server. Try changing that to TCP and you should observe an immediate performance drop. Connector/J, on the other hand, creates TCP based connections by default (Unix Domain Sockets can be used but only by using a third party library).

Also, in mysqlslap you are running a simple query directly, which are handled by a COM_QUERY protocol command. In the Java sample you are preparing the query first and then executing it. Depending on how Connector/J is configured this may result in a single COM_QUERY protocol command or a pair of commands, namely, COM_STMT_PREPARE and COM_STMT_EXECUTE. Connector/J is also affected by how its statement caches are configured (and/or the CP ones). However, you are only measuring the `executeQuery` part so, theoretically, Connector/J could be being favored here.

Finally, unless you actually come up with a use case where you guarantee that both executions are effectively doing the same work under the same circumstances, you can compare results and point out differences, but you can't take any conclusions from it. For example, it's not that hard to introduce caches and make those simple iterations even completely skip communicating to the server... that would make things extremely fast.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your thoughts here. I've gone ahead and implemented the Unix Domain Sockets library `junixsocket` to compare performance. The computation time is identical with Hikari (TCP). Mysqlslap still runs blazingly faster. I'm kind of stumped. We're achieving ~1ms per query in JDBC, compared to ~.3ms per query in slap. I also went ahead added the --protocol=tcp flag in the slap query and the time was unchanged. I'm beginning to think that it is just impossible to reduce the JDBC time of 1ms down to that sweet ~.3ms we're seeing in slap, but maybe you have ideas. What do you think?

Comment: I can't speak for `junixsocket`, but I would expect some slowdown from Connector/J when compared to mysql command line tools. The latter are implemented in C and use the `libmysqlclient` so they are closer to the "bare metal".

Comment: You say that adding `--protocol=tcp` didn't change the results, but this is not what I'm seeing:
```Average number of seconds to run all queries: 1.004 seconds```
vs 
```Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.137 seconds```
in my machine

Answer (score 0):

move borrowing connection and Stopwatch related code out of method. then measure as:

```
 Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.createStarted();
 try (Connection con = ....)  {
     for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)  {
            queryUsername(   con   );
      }
 }
 s.stop();
 print s.elapsed(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```

Comment: This has been measured. It took 872ms. The bulk of the time is from the queryUsername() method. As per the OP 776ms of the 872ms runtime is from queryUsername(). There are no improvements when using a single connection versus using a connection obtained via the HikariDataSource pool.

Comment: check DBCore.getConnection() for any options set for connection.. eg  transaction isolation level, auto commit, read only, schema, various cache options... default settings for some of these may be different for jdbc and mysqlslap

Comment: Monitor GC activity during run. also measure using https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

Comment: may be --iterations instead of --number-of-queries tobe used for mysqlslap?